# Error: Variable in lenghts differ in R (but they do not..)

Tags: r

This indeed looks like easy error message to solve, but I've been struggling with it the entire morning and I don't really see why I get this message, but maybe one of you is more familiar with this problem. I made a testdataset to illustrate my question:

```
> test
      PatientID Age Gender     Date Group var1 var2 var3
    1         1  70   Male 1/1/2015   A_0 0.30    4  117
    2         1  70   Male 1/6/2015   A_1 0.70    9   90
    3         2  52 Female 1/1/2015   A_0 1.00    1   87
    4         2  52 Female 1/8/2015   A_1 2.00   11  103
    5         3  49   Male 1/3/2015   A_0 0.25   14  111
    6         3  49   Male 1/8/2015   A_1 0.30    5   50
    7         4  36 Female 1/3/2015   A_0 0.70    7   82
    8         4  36 Female 1/6/2015   A_1 0.80    8  133

> library(broom)
> lapply(names(test)[6:9], function(n) {
+   linear <- lm(n ~ Group + Age + Gender + Date, data = test)
+   lapply(linear, glance)
+ })
 Error in model.frame.default(formula = n ~ Group + Age + Gender + Date,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'Group')
```

When I try to run the same regression on one of the variables I don't get the error message:

```
> summary(lm(var1 ~ Group + Age + Gender + Date))

    Call:
    lm(formula = var1 ~ Group + Age + Gender + Date)

    Residuals:
           1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8 
    -0.03321 -0.06578  0.03321  0.09672  0.19571 -0.09672 -0.19571  0.06578 

    Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
    (Intercept)  -1.19491    0.68201  -1.752   0.2219  
    GroupA_1      0.93650    0.26436   3.543   0.0713 .
    Age           0.04157    0.01234   3.368   0.0780 .
    GenderMale   -1.38185    0.25128  -5.499   0.0315 *
    Date1/3/2015  0.59406    0.32438   1.831   0.2085  
    Date1/6/2015 -0.50393    0.23247  -2.168   0.1625  
    Date1/8/2015       NA         NA      NA       NA  
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    Residual standard error: 0.2304 on 2 degrees of freedom
    Multiple R-squared:  0.9536,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8375 
    F-statistic: 8.216 on 5 and 2 DF,  p-value: 0.112
```

I did some diagnostics to check wether these factors really have only one level, but it seems not to be the case...

```
    > l<-sapply(test,function(x)is.factor(x))
    > l
    PatientID       Age    Gender      Date     Group      var1      var2      var3 
        FALSE     FALSE      TRUE      TRUE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
    > m<-test[,names(which(l=="TRUE"))]
    > m
      Gender     Date Group
    1   Male 1/1/2015   A_0
    2   Male 1/6/2015   A_1
    3 Female 1/1/2015   A_0
    4 Female 1/8/2015   A_1
    5   Male 1/3/2015   A_0
    6   Male 1/8/2015   A_1
    7 Female 1/3/2015   A_0
    8 Female 1/6/2015   A_1
    > ifelse(n<-sapply(m,function(x)length(levels(x)))==1,"DROP","NODROP")
      Gender     Date    Group 
    "NODROP" "NODROP" "NODROP"
```

So it would be really great if somebody has a suggestion to overcome this at first sight easy error?

New script after suggestion underneath:

```
attach(test)
lapply(names(test)[6:8], function(n) {
  linear <-as.formula(paste(n, "~ Group + Age + Gender + Date"))
  glance(lm(linear, na.action=na.omit))
})
```

I also incorporated now how to handle missing values.

Thank you very very much for the suggestion, because I wasn't seeing it clearly anymore this morning!!

Comment: You can't put the variable `n` inside a formula. It will be treated as the literal name `n`. The way to do it would be `as.formula(paste(n, "~ Group + Age + Gender + Date"))`.

Comment: Thanks!! I edited my question with the correct command incorporating your suggestion!